# Why is company mode not working with company-tng?

Tags: company-mode

I've got a setup like the following in my `init.el`

```
(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :after lsp-mode
  :hook (after-init . global-company)
  :bind
  (:map company-active-map
    ("<tab>" . company-complete-selection))
  (:map lsp-mode-map
    ("<tab>" . company-indent-or-complete-common))
  :custom
  (company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
  (company-idle-delay 0.0))

(use-package company-box
  :after company-mode
  :hook (company-mode . company-box-mode))
```

However, I keep seeing the error `failed to define Autoloading file /Users/nland/.emacs.d/straight/build/company/company-tng.el failed to define function company-tng-mode` I have no idea why this is happening. I've looked in `company-tng.el` and there is no function `company-tng-mode` and I'm kind of lost now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I clearly jumped the gun on asking this question, I've figured out the issue. The issue was that I was using an out-of-date version of `company`, I think the issue was more with `straight.el` than `company`, but after an update, I'm back in business.

Comment: nland, consider [accepting your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved the problem you had.